# Phonegap CLI Error: Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-cli

im new to phonegap, ive tried almost everything i see but heres my problem,i create a new project like this

phonegap create myApp

then i go into my new project with cd myApp,IM ON THE WORKING DIRECTORY,then i try to add a plugin like this

phonegap plugin add phonegap-plugin-camera

there is when i get the error, i can do

phonegap serve

and this works find when i access the port in my browser, except for the missing favicon , i get the same error when executing

phonegap platform add android

my phonegap version is 6.2.9,
thank you

Comment: http://prntscr.com/bsvygl   this is the structure i get from the created project

Comment: Try a different command line shell and/or try running it with admin privileges.

Comment: @AbhishekJain done , http://prntscr.com/btacc7, still not working, thank you